# bpython -i & namespaces

Tags: python, namespaces, ipython, interactive, bpython

I can't seem to find this answer anywhere.

Given the trivial example:

```
# myclass.py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print 'test'

def main():
    my_class_instance = MyClass()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

some_var = 'i exist!  ... but I think I'm in global namespace?'
```

If I run bpython -i myclass.py, I execute the program & drop into the bpython environment.  Whatever namespace I'm in - my_class_instance does not exist.  However, some_var does exist - and so does the main function itself.

Is there anyway that I can pull any objects that exist in that main function into the namespace I'm in when I drop into that interactive prompt?  Or is there something else I should do?

Answer (score 1):

`my_class_instance` is in `main`'s namespace, so you can't see it outside of `main`. Use a global instead:

```
my_class_instance = None

def main():
    global my_class_instance

    my_class_instance = MyClass()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another trick I sometimes use when I want something back from running a main function is to return what I need at the end of main.

So, for example if I need an instance and some other variable from the main function in the top level one could do:

```
def main():
    myclass = MyClass()
    a = 4
    return (my class, a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ret = main()
```

If you now call your script with bpython -i scriptname you will have the variable 'ret' in the global namespace and ret[0] has your class instance, ret[1] has the number 4.

Answer (score 0):

Using interactive bpython over python 2.7, `__name__` is equal to `__console__`. So your function `main()` may be never called. A hack would be to write:

```
# myclass.py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print 'test'

def main():
    global my_class_instance
    my_class_instance = MyClass()

if __name__ in ('__main__', '__console__'):
    main()
```